# ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, linker-errors

I have already raised this kind query, still I did not get any helpful answers, so that, I am posting this again.

I am installing firebase, googlesigin, twitterkit and fabric to my swift application by Cocoapods.

If I installed only Fabric I am able to compile and run the application. But, If I tried to install GoogleSignIn and TwitterKit, Fabric, its installing successfully, but, not able to run, getting compiler error of following.

```
    ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And my podfile is like following.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'pod installation' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  # Pods for sample pod

  # Pods for pod installation

  target 'pod installationTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[image]

**Attached screenshot, any help from anyone. I am trying to fix this from two days and Really thanks for who helping this fix.**

Note : I am using Xcode 8.3.2 and I don't have any real device with me now, and I am not using any FileProvider framework in my application.

Comment: Does it build for an iOS Device (not simulator)? Can you show the content of the pods folder with the FileProvider? Is it a dynamic Library or static Library?

Comment: I don't have any real device with me now, and I am not using any FileProvider framework.

Comment: 1) Can you select generic device and Build the project? 2) I think you already tried to close Xcode, delete all derived data and compile the project again?

Comment: I followed your suggestions and getting following error ld: framework not found IOSurface for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Perhaps your pods using  [FileProvider-framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider).
- [FileProvider-framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) is available from **iOS11.0 +** with **Xcode 9** hence You should upgrade with **Xcode 9** to avail this framework.

Comment: by using xcode 8.3.2, we can't fix this, you meant?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper As you are using many pods they may use `FileProvider`. In other way you can check with every pod weather its providing support for previous version of iOS? perhaps NOT. Best is to upgrade your Xcode to **9**

Comment: I understand, I looked for Xcode 8.3.2 version fixes, as of now, later I can switch to Xcode 9. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Finally, I installed Xcode 9 and few other issues came, fixes.